# Recover Cygwin after MKS Toolkit installation

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin

I used to use Cygwin on my Windows desktop for a while and was happy until I installed some other app recently. This app itself is not relevant here (let's call it ABC app), the main thing that it has installed MKS Toolkit along with it. Since I was installing the app as administrator the installation manager added MKS Toolkit at the beginning of system PATH variable. Now MKS Toolkit shadows/hides Cygwin and Cygwin is actually broken. I could remove MKS Toolkit from system PATH, as I'm not going to use it directly, but I'm not sure how it will affect the ABC app.

**The question is**: Is there any way I can keep MKS Toolkit at the beginning of system PATH and use Cygwin at the same time? If yes, then what should be done for this?

This is how I had run Cygwin (the default shortcut actually):

```
<my_path_to_cygwin>\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
```

What I have in Cygwin now:

```
echo $PATH
C:\Program Files (x86)\MKS Toolkit\mksnt;C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~in64;C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~in;C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~in\X11;...the rest of the PATH...

which bash
C:/Program Files (x86)/MKS Toolkit/mksnt/bash.exe
```

What I have in cmd.exe:

```
echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files (x86)\MKS Toolkit\mksnt;C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~1\bin64;C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~1\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~1\bin\X11;...the rest of the PATH...

which bash
C:/Program Files (x86)/MKS Toolkit/mksnt/bash.exe
```

Side note: I also have GitBash and seems it has not been affected by MKS Toolkit.

What I have in GitBash:

```
$ echo $PATH
/c/Users/<username>/bin:.:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/MKS Toolkit/mksnt:/c/PROGRA~2/MKSTOO~1/bin64:/c/PROGRA~2/MKSTOO~1/bin:/c/PROGRA~2/MKSTOO~1/bin/X11:...the rest of the PATH...
$ which bash
/bin/bash
```

Comment: Why Cygwin should be broken ? It redefines its own path with PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"` so the Cygwin programs are always coming first.

Comment: matzeri, I had added the result of `which bash` execution. As you can see mintty starts bash from MKS Toolkit, not from Cygwin. The same case is for all other UNIX-like programs, that are in `MKS Toolkit\mksnt` directory: cp, less, vi etc.

Comment: matzeri, I've found where cygwin redefines its own path that you mentioned - it's in `/etc/profile`, right? But looks like it is not executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read mintty man carefuly (https://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html) and found that:

```
If a program name is supplied on the command line, this is executed with any additional arguments given. Otherwise, mintty looks for a shell to execute in the SHELL environment variable. If that is not set, it reads the user’s default shell setting from /etc/passwd. As a last resort, it falls back to /bin/sh.
```

So, I added a user-level env variable `SHELL` with `/bin/bash` value and it recovered my Cygwin. I dind't have to modify mintty shortcut target.